# Update value in object field checkbox by clicking custom button

Tags: javascript, custom-field, onclick

I want to know how to update check box object field. Currently the check box by default the value is uncheck(false). But I want when user click yes button, the check box object field(yellow highlighted in image) will be change to true. You may refer the image below for better understanding.

[image]

[image]

Currently I just do as below. But it doesnt work.

```
{!Return_Shipment__c.Final_Approved__c} == true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var newRecordsfalse = [];
var L = new sforce.SObject("ret__c");
L.id ="{!ret__c.Id}";
L.Final_Approved__c = false;
newRecordsfalse.push(L);
results = sforce.connection.update(newRecordsfalse);
window.location.reload();
```

Here is the answer. It is work for me.